# MySQL Slow ORDER BY ASC on primary key

Tags: mysql, performance

I faced the problem with very slow SELECT with order by.
I have a table, ENGINE=MyISAM, it has 26 millions rows so far.

When I run

```
SELECT a.amount FROM billing WHERE user_id = 102458 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100
```

everything ok, it executed less than 0.5 s

But when I run

```
SELECT a.amount FROM billing WHERE user_id = 102458 ORDER BY id LIMIT 100
```

it executed more than 1 minute.
`id` is the primary key.

EXPLAIN is the same for both queries

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | a |  | index | user_hash,user_id | PRIMARY | 4 |  | 81351 | 0.61 | Using where |

MySQL Ver: 5.7.32

**Update:**
The problem that if specify `order by` it does not use `user_id` index. If you look at the extra field in EXPLAIN you'll see that mysql use `where`. User 102458 is a new user, so all entries in this table located in the end that's why DESC works fast, and ASC slow. If I change user_id to some old user ASC starts to work fast and DESC slow.

Comment: run the query with ASC as sorting

Comment: ASC is redundant here, but anyway, it still slow with ASC

Answer (score 0):

it has something to do with the order of the index, as it is already sorted DESC and so a ASC would need a sort that takes time.

see (which is for maysql 8, but i think ot will apply for 5.7 also

https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/10/20/mysql-8-0-descending-indexes-can-speedup-your-queries/#

You can experiment for your query is to add a INDEX on user_id or a combined user_id,id ASC for the order with ASC

Comment: I tried to add index ordered by asc but it does not help. I think the problem in user_id index, it's not used.

Comment: add a HINT index name to your query, also you can see in the explain if ine is used

Answer (score 0):

(You really should switch to InnoDB.)

For MyISAM, the optimal index is

```
INDEX(user_id, id, amount)
```

That is "composite" and "covering".  The query with be run entirely in the index's BTree.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't right now change the engine. Also, there are a lot of other fields that i need to make a search. Maybe I don't need to use ORDER BY primary key in this case? id is autoincement

Comment: Because you use `LIMIT` you should always specify an `ORDER BY`, because ASC will get the first 100 records, and DESC will get the last 100 records. (because of the LIMIT 100)

Comment: @DaartKote - If you did not supply the 'real' query, then my Answer may not be the 'real' answer.